# Find $\vec{n}$ such that $e^{-i\alpha S_z} e^{-i\beta S_y} e^{-i\gamma S_z} = e^{-i \vec{n} \cdot \vec{S}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

Any idea how to effciently find vector $\vec{n}$ in the formula
$$e^{-i\alpha S_z} e^{-i\beta S_y} e^{-i\gamma S_z} = e^{-i \vec{n} \cdot \vec{S}},$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are given and $\vec{S} = (S_x, S_y, S_z)$ and operators $S_i$ satisfy commutation relations $[S_i, S_j] = \epsilon_{ijk}S_k$? I know how to do it graphically with rotation on a sphere, but I am looking for a different method, solely algebraical, which I could apply to larger groups e.g. SU(3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start from the remarkably simple "Gibbs formula" [generic group composition law for SU(2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#The_group_composition_law_of_SU(2)) in terms of Pauli matrices, the defining (so, faithful) representation of SU(2). As a group identity, the result will then hold for all representations! Note however, you have chosen your *S* antihermitian, and I'm sure you don't mean that, as they do not give you unitary exponentials. With an *i* on the r.h.s. of their Lie algebra, they'd be hermitian generators of SU(2), so then *half* the corresponding Pauli matrices. I'll just let you clean up your normalizations to your satisfaction, and multiply the Pauli-half-angle analog of your two exponentials, leaving the second, messier, multiplication for you.

$$
e^{ia \sigma_z} e^{ib \sigma_y}  \\
= \exp \left ( i \frac{\arccos (\cos a ~ \cos b)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 a \cos^2 b } } ~ (\sigma_z \sin a \cos b + \sigma_y \sin b \cos a + \sigma_x \sin a \sin b) \right ),
$$
basically [the simplest formula of spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

You will not have such luck for SU(3), of course. With judicious maneuvering, you might be able to use [this rep fact](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(15)30040-9).